# How do I customise the Ember store path for a specific model?

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I have an API endpoint at `/movies/:movie_id/actors`.

I'm trying to use Ember Data to fetch this endpoint. I'm not interested in modelling movies at this point, just actors. My route looks like this:

```
this.route('actors', { path: '/movies/:movie_id/actors' });
```

My actor model is plain:

```
DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr("name")
})
```

In my actors route, I have:

```
model: function(params) {
  // params contains movie_id
  return this.store.findAll('actor')
}
```

This will cause Ember to send a request for `/actors`. How can I tell Ember to send a request to `/movies/:movie_id/actors` instead?

My JSON is being returned in the format `{ "movies": [ { … } ] }` and I'm using the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter`, if that's at all relevant. I'm using Ember 2.0.

Comment: Take a look at the `buildURL` hook.

Comment: Is ember-data a hard requirement for the project?

Comment: @ToranBillups No, not a hard requirement. I've been wondering about the value of using it.

Comment: Honestly I'd skip the complexity if you don't absolutely _need_ ember-data. Learning ember and rich client dev at the same time is enough (speaking from my experience -some might disagree). If you just need $.ajax + a simple in memory cache you suddenly have a TON of flexibility on basic data flow. Here is a simple ember example with $.ajax + a really basic in memory cache (just push/find objects essentially) https://github.com/toranb/pods-with-components-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DS.Store doesn't work around "path" concept. It's more of a data bucket, which - when supplemented - can take burden of working with provider (fetch/update/create/cache etc.) off developer. In your case it looks similar to this:

[image: Using DS.Store for data]

ActiveModelAdapter, which you're using right now is using specific convention for accessing and isn't compatible with your data provider. So, what options do you have?

1. Customize ActiveModelAdapter by overriding [pathForType](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_pathForType) or [buildURL](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL) methods (note - links are for RESTAdapter, since ActiveModelAdapter subclasses it)
2. Choose more compatible adapter or even [write your own](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#toc_creating-an-adapter)
3. Don't use adapter - fetch the data through AJAX and feed it to store directly using [push()](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push)/[pushPayload()](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload)